# Use of % in a string

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and we're currently learning how to use if/elif/else and as a exercise our prof. wants us to write a program that answers if a year is a leap year or not.I found a guide that shows and gives you a pretty good explanation on how to write such a program.

The code looks like this:

```
year = int(input("Please Enter the Year Number you wish: "))

if (year%400 == 0):
          print("%d is a Leap Year" %year)
elif (year%100 == 0):
          print("%d is Not the Leap Year" %year)
elif (year%4 == 0):
          print("%d is a Leap Year" %year)
else:
          print("%d is Not the Leap Year" %year
```

The only thing I am trying to figure out but haven't been able to find a good answer to is why the author uses `print("%d this is a leap year" %year)`

How come `%d` when the running the program doesn't show up as `%d` when inside a string?

Comment: Read [5.6.2. String Formatting Operations — Python 2.7.17 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: you should read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time sending these links.! I'll check them out.

Comment: You may be interested to review https://pyformat.info/ Also note that as of python 3.6 latest and most convenient method is to use f-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here %d inside the string is a format specifier which means that it will be replaced with the integer value provided after the end of the string.
It is just a placeholder for the year value.

Answer (score -1):

**%d** means you are expecting an **integer** **int32** after the **string** which in your case is the year after each print statement.

for the same example you cna use Format method as well

```
print ("is a Leap Year : {}".format(year))
```

Comment: I see! Thank you! I'll look into using the Format function.

Comment: Strictly speaking correct term for `str.format()` is method, not function

Comment: @LukeRhinehart_ if this is what you were looking for please consider accepting the answer